# How to pass Magick::Image object to carrierwave uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave, rmagick

I'm using Magick to convert PDF pages to images and Carrierwave for file storing management.

This is the method that i'm using and it works:

```rb
  def convert_to_images
    user_cv_images.destroy_all
    Magick::ImageList.new(self.file.file.file) do
      self.quality = 100
      self.density = 144
      self.colorspace = Magick::RGBColorspace
      self.interlace = Magick::NoInterlace
    end.each_with_index do |image, index|
      tmp_file_path = "tmp/page-#{index}.png"
      image.resize_to_fit!(1600, 10000)
      image.write(tmp_file_path)
      user_cv_images.create(image: File.open(Rails.root.join(tmp_file_path), position: index + 1))
      File.delete(Rails.root.join(tmp_file_path))
    end
  end
```

The thing that's bothering me is that i'm saving each of those images to tmp/ folder to have a way of passing it to the Carrierwave uploader. I'm pretty certain that there is a better way to do that but i'm unable to find it.

The image is an object of `Magick::Image` class.

Comment: I guess you can [use IO](https://makandracards.com/makandra/50526-fileio-writing-strings-as-carrierwave-uploads) and [image.to_blob](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rmagick/Magick%2FImage:to_blob)

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me in the end, thanks to [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1423219/phil) and his suggestion:

I have added the FileIO helper in my initializers:

```rb
#config/initializers/file_io.rb
class FileIo < StringIO
  def initialize(stream, filename)
    super(stream)
    @original_filename = filename
  end

  attr_reader :original_filename
end

FileIO = FileIo
```

And now my method for saving the images looks like this:

```rb
  def convert_to_images
    user_cv_images.destroy_all
    Magick::ImageList.new(self.file.file.file) do
      self.quality = 100
      self.density = 144
      self.colorspace = Magick::RGBColorspace
      self.interlace = Magick::NoInterlace
    end.each_with_index do |image, index|
      image.resize_to_fit!(1600, 10000)
      user_cv_images.create(image: FileIO.new(image.to_blob, "page-#{index}.png"), position: index + 1)
    end
  end
```